# Getting error while creating wildcard ssl using certbot

Tags: ssl, certbot

I am using certbot to create wildcard ssl certificate. I am using the below command to create a wildcard ssl certificate.

```
sudo certbot certonly — manual — preferred-challenges=dns — email sujith@website.com — server https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory — agree-tos -d *.website.com
```

I am getting the below error,

```
certbot: error: unrecognized arguments: —manual —preferred-challenges=dns —email sujith@website.com —server https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory —agree-tos
```

Kindly help me fixing this issue.

Comment: **You're not using hyphens.** You're using the Unicode "em-dash" character, U+2014. Like most commandline programs, certbot uses two hyphens (U+002D) for 'long' options (like `--manual`) and one hyphen for single-letter short options (like `-d`), but never any other dash. If you cut&paste this from a word-processor or a website, those often try to make your text 'look nice' rather than contain the correct character(s); type the correct value, including hyphens, instead.

Comment: Great. Thank you. Fixed the issue just before some time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I myself fixed the issue, It was due to `-` in the place of `--`. The command should be like,

```
sudo certbot certonly --manual --preferred-challenges=dns --email sujith@website.com --server https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory --agree-tos -d *.website.com
```